# Setting logical values for Common/Random and Hartung-Knap adjustment based on condition (number of studies)

Tags: r, correlation, metafor, meta-analysis

I am trying to do a common and random effects meta-analysis of correlations with and without hartung knap adjustment. Based on conditions, I want to set the hakn argument of the meta package as TRUE or FALSE depending on the number of studies I have per subgroup. If I have more than 2 studies per subgroup, the random arument should be set to TRUE and the common should be FALSE. In addition, the hakn argument should be set to be TRUE. If the number of studies per subgroup is more than 2, I need to set the common argument to be TRUE but random to be FALSE and hakn also to be FALSE. This will be helpful for me to do a case-by-case choice of meta-analysis approach. Unfortunately, doing it based on such conditions hasn't worked for me. Is there any way to set them by conditions? I have included a reproducible data set.

NB: Ignore the high heterogeneity stat.

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Specify the number of studies in each subgroup
num_studies <- c(2, 3, 5)

# Create data for all subgroups
simulated_data <- data.frame(
    Subgroup = rep(paste("Corr", LETTERS[1:length(num_studies)], "*Y"), times = num_studies),
    Study = rep(paste("Study", 1:sum(num_studies)), each = 1),
    SampleSize = c(50,60, 40, 90, 100, 120, 90, 70, 80, 130),
    Correlation = runif(sum(num_studies), -1, 1)
)
```

## Perform the meta-analysis of correlations

`res <- metacor(cor = Correlation,n = SampleSize,subgroup = Subgroup,data = simulated_data)`

## Print the summary of the meta-analysis

```
forest.meta(res, subgroup.name = "",
            studlab = Study, 
            test.subgroup = F, overall = F,
            overall.hetstat = F,
            fontsize = 9,
            spacing = 0.7,
            col.subgroup = "#00868B")
```

[image]
I tried to do it by counting the subgroup and merging it with my data frame and setting it based on conditions(subgroup count) but it wasn't successful.